# how to use element tree in this code to find a specific element

Tags: python

I have this code that moves all the jpegs, txts and xmls from one directory to another. i would like the create a loop that find a element inside the xml file and if it does exist it there, than it will move the file and if not it will keep the file in the directory. maybe someone can give me an advice?
this is my code so far:

```py
import os
import glob
import shutil


def remove_ext(list_of_pathnames):
    """
    removes the extension from each filename
    """
    return [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in list_of_pathnames]

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("D:\\TomProject\\")
os.mkdir("Done")  # create a new folder
newpath = os.path.join("D:\\TomProject\\", "Done")  # made it os independent... 

list_of_jpegs = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpeg'))
list_of_xmls = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml'))
list_of_txts = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))
print(path)

print(list_of_jpegs, "\n\n", list_of_xmls, "\n\n", list_of_txts,
      "\n\n")  # remove

jpegs_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_jpegs)
xmls_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_xmls)
txts_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_txts)

for filename in jpegs_without_extension:
    if filename in xmls_without_extension:
        if filename in txts_without_extension:
            print("moving", filename)  # remove
            shutil.move(filename + '.jpeg', newpath)  # move image to new path.
            shutil.move(filename + '.xml', newpath)
            shutil.move(filename + '.txt', newpath)
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? What errors do you have?

Comment: right now i dont have any errors i just need the directions from someone that knows how to use element tree to loop through the xml files in my directory

Comment: Your described intention, "code that moves all the jpegs, txts and xmls", doesn't match your code, "code that moves *only* the files appearing with all 3 suffixes: jpegs, txts and xmls". Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.